# Using std::apply with variadic packs

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdapply

I am trying to create a generic class that takes a pack of types, stores them in a tuple, and can apply a function over them.

What I tried so far is the following:

```
#include <tuple>
struct Base{
    virtual void base_function() = 0;
};

template<typename ...T>
struct A : public Base{
    std::tuple<T...> as;
    A(T... pack):as(pack...){};
    void base_function(){
        std::apply([](auto t){t.base_function();}, as);
    }
};

struct B : public Base{
    void base_function(){};
};


struct C : public Base{
    void base_function(){};
};

struct D : A<B, C>{
    D():A(B(),C()){};
};
```

I expected apply to be called on base_function from class B and C when calling base_function on D. But the compiler generates the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   '`__invoke(A<T>::base_function() [with T = {B, C}]::<lambda(auto:1)>,
>   std::__tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<B, C> >&,
>   std::__tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<B, C> >&)`'

Comment: Just so you know, the `Base` and `D` classes (and any inheritance from `Base`) aren't necessary for a minimal example. Your problem manifests itself the same way (and @Jarod42's solution works the same way) even without them.

Comment: @Spencer Removing the D class doesn't generate the error because the compiler doesn't generate any code without a version of A being declared. The base class was there when slimming down the code and is there to give some context

Comment: But you could have just declared an `A<B,C>` wherever you declared the `D` object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First parameter of [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) should be a functor with same arity that number of elements of the tuple, so variadic in your case:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct A : public Base{
    std::tuple<Ts...> as;
    A(Ts... pack) : as(pack...){}

    void base_function(){
        std::apply([](auto&... ts){(ts.base_function(), ...);}, as);
    }
};
```

Comment: Never seen the syntax used in the lambda, could you explain a bit more what it's actually doing. How does the compiler know what to do on the parameter pack `ts`?

Comment: Look at [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

Comment: This is great, but you might want to add an explanation as to why `std::apply` doesn't work the way OP thought it did.

Answer (score 4):

`std::apply` is not doing what you think. It is for a passing a tuple of parameters to a function (Callable type). In other words, the tuple itself doesn't have a function called `base_function`. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply

Comment: I'd interpret OP's confusing as thinking `apply` takes a unary function and applies it to each element in the tuple in turn, not as applying a unary function directly to the tuple (which would be pointless, as you could just... do it already).